# Angularjs $http.post but asp.net 5 controller gets null

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core

In my angularjs code I have this:

```
$http.post("Home/PostData", {name:'Peter',age:18}).success(function (response) {

});
```

And I have this method in my asp.net 5 controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostData(string name,int age)
{

}
```

I've put a break point on the method and it gets fired, but my name is  null and age is 0.

I have done that before by using asp.net mvc 5 and that worked.

Why is wrong in asp.net 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller code like below:

```
public class PostModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostData([FromBody]PostModel model)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you adem caglin, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
$http.post("Home/PostData", { params: {name:'Peter',age:18}}).success(function (response) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $http.post("Home/PostData",{ name: "Peter", age:18}).success(function (response){

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case controller parameter name is same name as property in the model. Its failing because of that reason.

For Ex- in controller
public JsonResult Method(BindingModel **firstname**, ViewState viewState)

in BindingModel--

class BindingModel{
string **firstname**,
string lastname
}